# displaying objects in a spinner rather than just strings

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm building a dialog with a spinner. When the dialog is done, it calls a method of the parent activity with a string argument - the argument being the string value that was selected.

**My current approach:**
I'm setting up the spinner's array adapter like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
    categoryNames);     

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`categoryNames` is a string array. When the dialog is done, the selected `categoryName` is used as the parameter to the method call on the parent activity.

**What I really want to do:**
What I actually want is to display a list of `Category` objects. The `Category` class has 2 properties - `categoryId` and `categoryName`. The spinner should still display the `categoryName`s in the drop-down view, but when the dialog is done, it should be able to unambiguously tell which `Category` was selected, and call the parent activity's callback method with the `categoryId` of the category that was selected.

There can be multiple `Category`ies with the same `categoryName`.

**Question:** How to do the above?

Comment: While I already posted an answer, if the Category names aren't unique how will _the user_ tell the difference between with the same name (for example, "music" and "music")?

Comment: i've used the "category" and "categoryName" metaphor to simplify my use case :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple different way to do what you want:

- Store the extra data in the adapter, like a SimpleAdapter, SimpleCursorAdapter, or custom one.
- Use a Collection of custom objects instead of Strings, simply override the `toString()` method to present user readable Strings in the Spinner.

---

You seem to want to do the second option, so here's a generic example:

```
class Category {
    int id;
    String name;

    public Category(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Your ArrayAdapter is almost the same:

```
List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
// Add new items with: categories.add(new Category(0, "Stack");

ArrayAdapter<Category> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<Category>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        categories);

...
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Category category = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.v("Example", "Item Selected id: " + category.id + ", name: " + category.name);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
});
```

Comment: Hm, that presents a second challenge to me: when I pass in an array of `Category` objects to my dialog fragment (that's my dialog), how do I store it in the fragment's `arguments`? I could not find any `Bundle#setObjectArray()` method..

Comment: Ha! I just answered [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12503875/1267661) using Bundles to pass an ArrayList of custom objects.

Comment: Found your answer on parcelables very helpful :)

For the record, I went with the toString() approach (though from a purist standpoint, that's not really the right solution). Would be great if you could point me to some examples of how to build a custom adapter though.

Comment: Android's Romain Guy discusses [custom adapters](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) at Google I/O 2009. I love source code myself, if you don't have your own copy grepcode.com is a great source. (You can speed read some tutorials from a search engine as well.) A custom adapter won't help you too much if you only display one String, but as your object grows your app will receive measurable benefits.