# Write Object data to a parcel

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I want to Parcel the value that has datatype of "Object".
 For that I am using `writeValue(Object v)` method.

```
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(lockMemberScore);
        dest.writeValue(lockFollowedMemberScore);
        dest.writeValue(lockGroupAvgScore);
    }
```

But It is giving me the following error

```
01-01 11:22:00.479: E/SyncService(9647): Parcel: unable to marshal value java.lang.Object@4122e3c0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot write a generic object to a Parcel.

The [`writeValue(Object v)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29) can handle a long list of data types (available in the documentation) but a *generic* Object is not one of them... Basically your `v` is not: a primitive data type, Bundle, Map, etc and it does not implement Parcelable or Serializable; so `writeValue()` does know what to do with your particular Object.

Comment: ok @Sam so any otherway to marshal and unmarshal the generic object to parcel?

Comment: It's _really_ hard to say without more information. If you can turn this Object into a custom class that implements Parcelable then you can save this data to the Parcel.

Comment: I wrote an answer to another question awhile back that describes how to implement Parcelable, it may help you: [How to save custom ArrayList on Android screen rotate?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12503875/1267661).

Comment: I am using this Object for the synchronization.