# Best way to save a arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, android-adapter

This question has been answered before, but the solutions doesn't seem to work for me. I would like to know what the best way is to save an ArrayList.

I generate an ArrayList with all the installed applications on the phone. This list is shown in a ListView where the user can (de)select apps. This is all working fine. What I would like is that the Arraylist gets saved when the user presses a save button or when the activity calls onPause().

When the user returns to the list the user will see the list the way he saved/left it.

Here is my code:

**onCreate**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_list);

    loadApps();
    loadListView();
    addClickListener();
}
```

**loadApps**

```
private void loadApps(){
    manager = getPackageManager();
    apps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

    if(apps.size()==0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo ri : availableActivities) {
            AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
            app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
            app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
            app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
            app.allowed = false;
            apps.add(app);
        }
        Log.i("applist", apps.toString());
    }
}
```

**AppDetail.class**

```
public class AppDetail {
CharSequence label;
CharSequence name;
Drawable icon;
Boolean allowed;
```

**loadListView**

```
private void loadListView(){

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apps_list);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppDetail>(this, R.layout.list_item, apps) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps.get(position).icon);

            TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
            appLabel.setText(apps.get(position).label);

            TextView appName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
            appName.setText(apps.get(position).name);

            if(list.isItemChecked(position)){convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));}
            if(!list.isItemChecked(position)){convertView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));}
            return convertView;
        }
    };
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
```

**addClickListener**

```
private void addClickListener() {
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                                long id) {
            checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<AppDetail> allowedApps = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                // Item position in adapter
                int position = checked.keyAt(i);
                // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
                if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                    allowedApps.add(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("", allowedApps.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

At this moment I'm creating two lists:
List: list of all apps
AllowedApps: list of checked (allowed) apps, to use in an other activity

Comment: AFAIK, you need to find a way to save it to a file on internal storage and populate it from there.

Comment: You say that you've researched on the solutions and they don't work for you, please explain what exactly have you tried and why exactly it didn't suit your use case.

Comment: Serialize the list...

Comment: Should the selections be persisted even after the app is closed/the phone is shut down? If so you need to save to a database or a file. The list could actually be cleared even without closing the app. Read up on the Android lifecycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need saving your list when activity is paused, you have several ways to do it. First you need define the private list field in your activity.

```
private ArrayList<AppDetail> allowedApps;
```

**1) Make AppDetail serializable and use onSaveInstanceState**

```
public class AppDetail implements Serializable {
    CharSequence label;
    CharSequence name;
    Drawable icon;
    Boolean allowed;
}
```

**---------------- EDIT -----------------**

I would change `Drawable icon` field for `int icon`.

In your loadApps() method change the setence `app.icon = ri.activityInfo.getIconResource();`

In yout loadListView method change the setence `appIcon.setImageResource(apps.get(position).icon);`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("allowedApps", allowedApps);
}
```

Retrieve the list in onCreate method

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
     allowedApps = (List<AppDetail>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("allowedApps");
}else{
     allowedApps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();
}
```

**2) Use onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance**

Return the list in onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance

```
@Override
public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return allowedApps;
}
```

Retrieve the list in onCreate method

```
Object allowedApps= getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance();
if (allowedApps != null) {
    this.allowedApps = (List<AppDetail>) allowedApps;
}else{
    this.allowedApps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I implemented the first method. When i rotate the screen it will call the onSaveInstanceState. When I log the != null in the onCreate it logs the list correctly. When I click the recents button (the active apps) the app crashes `Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`

Comment: post the listener from the button.

Comment: For now i use an onClick method. Where i define the onClick in the xml file! Or did you mean the listener of the recents button?

Comment: post the method onClick then

Comment: `public void submitButton(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " List submitted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`

Comment: and app crash when you click the button?

Comment: No, it crashes when i click the Recents button (on some phones holding the home button for a longer period). It also crashes when i change the orientation twice (first time it works fine, When turning back to portrait is crashes)

Comment: ok, maybe it's a memory issue. You are saving a lot of Drawable objects. Try a change in your AppDetail, use id int resource instead of Drawable object. (activityInfo.getIconResource())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78437/discussion-between-developingbeaver-and-juanhl).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like **"Parcelable"**. It can save any ArrayList and retrieve back when you need it just like the Shared Preferences.

Please have a look here,

[How to save custom ArrayList on Android screen rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503836/how-to-save-custom-arraylist-on-android-screen-rotate)

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is serializable. Save it as a serializable object in file on storage