# Saving/Restoring custom ArrayList on Android screen rotate?

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable, screen-rotation, parcel

I have a custom ArrayList of MovieItems that I want to save and restore on screen rotation. I checked out this post - [How to save custom ArrayList on Android screen rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503836/how-to-save-custom-arraylist-on-android-screen-rotate) - and implemented and adapted some of the codes but the saving and restoring don't seem to be working for me.

1) Saving the ArrayList:

```
public List<MovieItem> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) mItems);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

2) Restoring the ArrayList:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {

            mItems = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(MOVIE_KEY);
        }
        setRetainInstance(true);
......

    }
```

3) Making the MovieItem class Parcelable:

```
public class MovieItem implements Parcelable{



    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String mCaption;
    private String mId;
    private String mUrl;
    private String plot;
    private Double rating;
    private String release_date;
    private boolean favourite;

    public MovieItem() {
    }

    protected MovieItem(Parcel in) {
        mCaption = in.readString();
        mId = in.readString();
        mUrl = in.readString();
        plot = in.readString();
        release_date = in.readString();
        favourite = in.readByte() != 0;
        mTitle = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<MovieItem> CREATOR = new Creator<MovieItem>() {
        @Override
        public MovieItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MovieItem(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MovieItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieItem[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {

        out.writeString(mCaption);
        out.writeString(mId);
        out.writeString(mUrl);
        out.writeString(plot);
        out.writeDouble(rating);
        out.writeString(release_date);

    }
```

Comment: What is "not working"?  Please explain what you expect to happen and how that's different from what is actually happening.

Comment: My list of movie posters were supposed to be restored when I turned off connection(airplane mode) and rotate the screen. But they were not restoring. But I got it restoring with  the selected answer below. Thanks.

Comment: The answer you accepted below is not a great general purpose solution.  You should not be handling config changes unless you absolutely know that you want your app to not behave like a normal Android app that responds correctly to configuration changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this line in your Manifest in relevant activity tag , and activity will handle rotation itself

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout"
```

test it maybe help you

Comment: you save my time, mamnunam ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because you have `setRetainInstance(true)`, the `Fragment` is not destroyed/recreated on screen rotation. The `Fragment` will call `onSaveInstanceState()` after a screen rotation, but the `onCreate()` portion will not occur.

Answer (score -1):

Use singletone object for storing your list. 
    public enum MySingleton {
    INSTANCE;
    private MySingleton() {
        System.out.println("Here");
    }
    private List mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    public List getItems(){
        return mItems;
    }
    }

and for access to your array from anywhere MySingleton.INSTANCE.getItems()

Answer (score -2):

You can try implementing the onRestoreInstanceState() method as well. Its called after the onStart() method. You can read up about it [onRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))