# Android refreshing adapter after change rotation device

Tags: android

in my below simple code, why my adapter can't refresh with added new data to that after change rotation device?

adding to adapter and refreshing that doesn't have any problem in first time, but after add some data to that and change device orientation.

i'm adding other data to that and i expect refresh with new added that, for example in fist time i add 1 data to adapter, the adapter can be know that and can be refresh with that, i see added data on adapter, after that, i change device orientation from for example `portrait` to `landscape`

now i add 1 data to adapter again, I expect adapter can be refresh with 2 added item.

adapter have 2 item but can't refresh with them, **that have a tip**:

**after change orientation device adapter can be refresh with last added items**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView  recyclerView;
    private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;
    private Movie         movie;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                movie = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2014");
                movieList.add(movie);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            movieList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("key");
            mAdapter.setData(movieList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            prepareMovieData();
        }
    }

    private void prepareMovieData() {
        movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
        movieList.add(movie);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("key", (ArrayList) movieList);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

MoviesAdapter:

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Movie> moviesList;
    public void setData(List<Movie> mMovieList) {
        moviesList.clear();
        moviesList.addAll(mMovieList);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title, year, genre;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
            year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
        }
    }


    public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
        holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

Movie:

```
public class Movie implements Parcelable {
    private String title, genre, year;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String title, String genre, String year) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.title = name;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    private Movie(Parcel in) {
        title = in.readString();
        genre = in.readString();
        year = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeString(genre);
        dest.writeString(year);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Movie> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Movie>() {
        public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Movie(in);
        }

        public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movie[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214600/save-data-and-change-orientation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126845/handle-screen-rotation-without-losing-data-android

Comment: @quicklearner thanks, after add item to `model` my adapter dont refresh with that, but after change orientation again, i see them on adapter, why?

Comment: u have to retain the items also

Comment: @quicklearner could you help me for resolve this problem?

Comment: okay let me see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144228/discussion-between-tux-world-and-quick-learner).

Comment: my problem resolve [by this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35707009/6596724) Thanks to @MahDi

Comment: i am glad it is solved