# How to store nested Arraylists in a Bundle in Android

Tags: java, android, onsaveinstancestate

I have this object in my Android App source code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObject>> rsp
```

and i want to store it in a Bundle and use it in `OnSaveInstanceState()` method in my activity. Then i want to retrieve it from the bundle, too.

Should i use json? Is there another way?

Comment: use `putParcelableArrayList()` in bundle and MyObject should implement Parcelable.

Comment: Does it work for nested arraylists?

Comment: Yes it should work for nested lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Parcelable to store the data in Bundle during OnSaveInstanceState()

use the below link for more details :

[How to save custom ArrayList on Android screen rotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503836/how-to-save-custom-arraylist-on-android-screen-rotate)

Answer (score 1):

If possible use `Gson` Library

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    String output = gson.toJson(rsp); // Create String and pass through bundle
```

Retrive that list from String

```
    //convert from string
String output =  // get that string from bundle
    ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObject>> fromString = gson.fromJson(output,new TypeToken<List<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyObject>>>>(){}.getType());
```